# Batch job on openshift

Tags: openshift, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We have to decide on batch processing framework/technology on OpenShift environmentusing Java.
Currently we are using springboot for Online application.
For batch processing we have below options,

1. Spring batch
2. Spring cloud data flow
3. Spring cloud task

One more thing is we should have monitoring UI/System/tool for the same, to know the status of processing, it is failed i should be able to rerun the btach from the monitoring ui.

I am not sure how best these things suits for Openshift, little confused like how to start?

A high level picture will definately help me to start.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [community-contributed](https://github.com/donovanmuller/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-openshift) implementation of OpenShift deployer/data flow server. But, it is pretty outdated and you may have to check that to find more info about it.

Comment: +1, you are one of the active person on web for the scdf doubts. can you please tell how can i schdule batch job using scdf ? aprt from registering task as stream (didnt work for me) then 
i found this, https://github.com/Manokethan/spring-cloud-scheduler-quartz but i am not sure how to use this. can you please help me out ?